# How to trigger an event after the completion of multiple, parallel CPF pipeline execution?

Tags: marklogic

I have a list of customer IDs. For each of them, I need to gather some information from external systems (through web services), and then create a report. After all the customer reports have been created, I would like to automatically generate a summary document based on all the reports.

My plan is to use the MarkLogic Content Processing Framework (CPF) to handle the web request and the report generation for each customer ID. However, I don't know how to trigger an action for the summary document after the completion of **all** the customer reporting pipelines.

[image]

#### Update based on [Mary's (@mholstege) response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54986419/3546482) (2019-03-04)

Based on my understanding of Mary's suggestion, I should instead have only one pipeline directly working on the customer IDs document, and create actions to process IDs sequentially, followed by a summary generation action at the terminal state. My only concern about this design is error handling as I can no longer rely on CPF states to track each individual report. How should I design states/actions to handle failure efficiently?

[image]

Comment: I'm wondering if MarkLogic Workflow could be a solution here. It is designed to work on batches of documents, rather than individual ones. See: https://developer.marklogic.com/code/workflow

Comment: Thanks, @grtjn. I am not familiar with marklogicworkflow and I will look into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is going to be very hard to get exactly right. You'll end up creating bottlenecks or gaps that may cause things to be skipped, or both. The general plan would be to have a transition after the "create report" that has a condition that checks the state of all the customer ids and launches the summary action if they are all in the right place. To make this have a hope of being reliable, you'll probably need to create a single document representing the batch and have the pipelines for the individual customer IDs update it (this will make sure there is a single latch that you can count on, the downside it is creates a single latch that they all will block on.) However, I would not recommend that, if you can avoid it.

CPF is designed to operate a series of steps over one document. So make the document it operates on be the batch, and have the actions be actions that work on the batch. This may mean the individual steps run longer (although if you have control over your webservice API you could make it batch oriented too, which may help), but your throughput may well end up being better. Do not, under any circumstances, spawn or invoke out of a CPF action.

Comment: Thanks, Mary. I have updated my question based on your suggestion. Could you please comment?

Answer (score 1):

Error handling design will be tricky, for sure, and there are trade-offs. You could either have all errors for any member of the batch cause a failure of the whole batch: the straightforward code would do that. Or, if you want to know all the failures in the batch, but still fail the batch, you could gather up all the individual errors and re-propogate them as a single wrapped failure, e.g. within the standard try/catch pattern in an action, something like:

```
let $errors := 
   for $id in $list-of-ids return
     try { let $work := do-stuff() return () } catch ($e) { <error><id>{$id}</id>{$e}</error> }
return
  if (empty($errors)) then ( (: OK! :) )
  else fn:error((), "MY-BATCHERROR", $errors)
```

That does make tagging individual documents with their own errors tricky, although you could add a transition for the error state that does that work: looking at the batch error and putting it on each of referenced documents.